# Treat NullPointerException appropriately

Tags: java, exception

I've got a PurchaseOrderList class with a following method, which returns an Array of objects in the list.

```
public PurchaseOrder [] getAllOrders()
{   
    PurchaseOrder [] ordersArray = new PurchaseOrder[listOfOrders.size()];

    if (listOfOrders.isEmpty())
        ordersArray = null;
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfOrders.size(); i++)
        {
            ordersArray[i] = listOfOrders.get(i);
        }

    return ordersArray;
}
```

If it is empty, it MUST return null!

I need to maintain 2 lists - one for the current and one for the last year. If it is a new year, the current year's data must be overwritten to lastYearList. And current year's list must be cleared. At the same time, discounts are based on totalOrdersValue the customer made during the relevant period, so I need to subtract the value of pasts orders for each customer from pastYearList, before it will get overwitten.

I've got the following, but don't know how to optimise it..

```
public void startNewMonth()
{
    PurchaseOrder [] lastYearArray = lastYearList.getAllOrders();
    PurchaseOrder [] currentYearArray = currentYearList.getAllOrders(); 

    try
    {
        if(lastYearList != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < lastYearArray.length; i++)
            {
                String foundID = lastYearArray[i].getCustomersID();
                int valueOfOrder = lastYearArray[i].getFullPriceValue();

                customersList.findCustomer(foundID).
                                      updateTotalOrdersValue(-valueOfOrder);
            }
        }

        System.arraycopy(currentYearArray, 0, lastYearArray, 0,
                                                   currentYearArray.length);            

        for(int i = 0; i < lastYearArray.length; i++)
        {
            lastYearList.addPurchaseOrder(lastYearArray[i]);
        }

        currentYearList.setListToEmpty();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

It seems that NullPointerException is thrown from the first line (if there is no data), but if I put it into 'try', the code gets very lengthy and I have to type a lot of the same stuff for different try as well as catch statements. I believe there is a short way to do that.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You don't use try/catch to avoid NullPointerException. You check for null using `if`. And you wouldn't have to check for null, and woudn't have those bugs if you did the right thing and NEVER returned a null array/list. Return an empty array/list instead.

Comment: only read the first part of code.. you have a method called `toArray()` instead of doing a for

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing this with arrays at all. Why are you not summarizing last year's orders, then assigning `currentYearList` to `lastYearList` as it is? The arrays are probably not the same length, and that will give you another error.

Comment: @ RealSkeptic   I have a list of orders there. I need go throuth each of those orders, check the ID of a customer, and subtract the orders' value from the record of their total orders value. Only do something with arrays.

Comment: That is it basically:    if(lastYearList != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < lastYearArray.length; i++)
            {
                String foundID = lastYearArray[i].getCustomersID();
                int valueOfOrder = lastYearArray[i].getFullPriceValue();

                customersList.findCustomer(foundID).
                                      updateTotalOrdersValue(-valueOfOrder);
            }

Comment: But how can I efficiently replace the old list with a new one? Considering all cases, if there is nothing in one list or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a good reason to have these intermediate arrays?

If you can add a `getOrders()` method to the `PurchaseOrderList` class, e.g.

```
List<PurchaseOrder> getOrders() { retur listOfOrders; }
```

Then you can simplify the `startNewMonth()`

```
public void startNewMonth() {
    if(lastYearList != null)
    {
        for(PurchaseOrder po : lastYearList.getOrders()) {
            String foundID = po.getCustomerID();
            int valueOfOrder = po.getFullPriceValue();
            customersList.findCustomer(foundID).updateTotalOrdersValue(-valueOfOrder);
        }

        for (PurchaseOrder po : currentYearList.getOrders()) {
            lastYearList.addPurchaseOrder(po);
        }

        currentYearList.setListToEmpty();
    }
}
```

Note that the logic of your method smells: the name is `startNewMonth` and you manage `yearList`...

Comment: Thank you very much, sorted it out!